# Punkbuster keeps kicking me for weird reasons. 'Invalid Memory Image'; how to resolve?

Tags: battlefield-3, origin, punkbuster

So on top of getting kicked from Battlefield 3 games because of a 'lost connection to EA online' error I just recently got this gem;

```
Game disconnected: you were kicked by PunkBuster.
Stated reason: PunkBuster kicked player 'Hashbrown777' (for 0 minutes) ...
RESTRICTION: Invalid Memory Image [130511]
```

I've had a bit of a look around and people seem to think it can be caused by modding (HUD modifications etc) but I have none.

I have no expansions and am just running the bare game. I repair installed and updated PB but they found nothing (said `no corruptions` and `already up to date` respectively).

I keep getting kicked for this and other reasons, but this one seems to be the most odd (and thus, hopefully, able to pinpoint a cause). Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I would try testing your computer's memory.  Maybe you have some flaky bits.

Comment: Personally, I'd try reinstalling punkbuster

Answer (score 1):

This may be a case of a macro application *or* PunkBuster mistaking its *own* memory writes as malicious ones.

By macro application, I mean something that fires off multiple clicks/keypresses when you hit another key. Do you have anything like this running? If so, perhaps try closing that before starting Battlefield. I had a similar issue with my Logitech keyboard and its "G-Keys".

By "memory writes" I mean modification to game data in your RAM, (which is where data such as your current health/velocity etc. reside). PunkBuster defends against this so players can't perform a lot of client-side hacks.

---

Source: http://answers.ea.com/t5/Battlefield-3/Punkbuster-problem/td-p/1446652

Comment: nah, no macros. I do use a Logitech G300 that *has* GKeys, but I don't use them for an FPS like Battlefield. 

If it really is punkbuster's own writes then surely this is an obscene bug

Comment: @Hashbrown Agreed, definitely leaning more towards the macro/system app being the cause. Hope you've had some luck!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with this particular issue but there may be a problem with your RAM.

- Is this Message displayed as a Message-Box or on Battlelog?
- Did you encounter similar problems with other games using a lot of RAM?
- How much RAM do you have installed? What Speed?
- How much RAM do you have left while playing?

I recently updgraded my RAM to 20GB (had 4GB before, which is the Minimum for Battlefield **4**) and I had a similar issue while playing BF4. I hat to close any program I didn't really use. I even closed the browser containing Battlelog after I joined the server.

Comment: I have 16gB (excluding gDDR), but it's interesting to think that maybe one of the sticks is faulty. I have had literally 0 problems on other RAM intensive applications though. 

I haven't played in a while, maybe I will in the coming weeks and see if a patch has magically fixed it. 

Thanks

Comment: And I don't remember vividly, but I'm pretty sure it was a BattleLog 'you were kicked, this is why' message and not a Windows 'your game crashed, memory issue'